# angular c3 directive not rendering in phantomjs 1.9.8 during unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, c3

I created a custom c3 directive to render a basic bar chart for an angular1.3.15 app.
The chart renders fine in chrome, but it doesn't seem to render during unit test. (using karma and phantomjs@1.9.8 from yeoman)

I already applied the MutationObserver and Bind pollyfill as dependencies to resolve phantomjs errors.

There are no errors in the console log and don't know what else could be causing c3 to not render properly.

Any suggestions?